# Copy an image with zclip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, copy, zclip

Is it possible to copy an image using zclip? I want to copy the actual image and the hyperlink using zclip instead of copying its HTML code.

Assuming that I have the following html part:

```
<div id="fooDiv">
 <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <img src="foo.png"/>
 </a>
</div>
```

I can get its html using the following copy function:

```
copy: function(){
   return $('#fooDiv').html();
}
```

So how can I replace this function in order to get the actual image instead of HTML. The reason I need this functionality is to be able to paste the result in e-mails immediately. HTML code won't benefit me.